# creating own collection class

Tags: c#, console

I am a new C# developer and I have been programming in 2 month now. I have now come to a part where I want to create an own collection class, but I have a few problems.

What do I want to do?
- I want to create an own generic collection class (list) for storing data. My class should have methods for adding item to the end of list or removing item from list.

- My Class should have properties for the number of items in the list and capacity of the iist.
- I must store the list in an array inside my class and the aray must have a predefined length.

so first I want to create an design and write down how my class should look like,where i only write down all the things that I need like methods, properties, and this is what ive done so far:

```
   public void Propertie () // depending on how many items I have, I create an propertie for each item
        {

        }
        public void addItems() // method for adding items 
        {

        }

        public void removeItems() // method for removing items
        {

        }

        int[] storeList; // array for storing the list 
    }
```

So before I start the real coding, I just want to know if i have missed or done something wrong?

Edit: I am Not allowed to use any of the c# collection or generic classes in this assignment.

Comment: What is your objective here? Why do you think creating your own collection class is required?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know if i have missed or done something wrong?

The design you're showing here is missing a few things.  First, you said you want to create a *generic* list.  How are you going to store generic data in an integer array?

Also, the signature you give for `addItems` is

```
public void addItems()
```

and the signature you give for `removeItems` is

```
public void removeItems()
```

How does your list object know what to add, if it isn't given any data?  Similarly, how does it know what to remove, if the client code doesn't tell it (you could always remove the first item, or always remove the last item, but then you're in stack or queue territory, not  the standard object-oriented list API).

I'd recommend looking at the API for [System.Collections.Generic.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), which is the built-in class you should be trying to emulate here.  You don't need to implement all the properties and methods that List implements, but you should implement parts of that API.  I would recommend

```
public sealed class MyList<T>
{
    public int Count { get; }
    public T this[int index] { get; set; }
    public MyList();
    public void Add(T item);
    public void RemoveAt(int index);
}
```

as the bare minimum API for a list class.  You'd implement it by declaring a field of type `T[]` as the backing store, plus an internal `size` field.  Don't forget that, if client code adds more items than the length of the backing store, you have to allocate a new backing store array (probably double the size of the old one), copy the elements to the new array, and start treating the new array as the backing store.

You should also look into implementing [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), which isn't strictly necessary, but makes a collection class much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've assured yourself that you really want to do this, you should consider:

1. What types you are going to support (you say generic, but have an int array in your example
2. How are you going to support access and iteration (e.g. will you support foreach, array style [])
3. how will the programmer specify the length (you say fixed length, does the programming specify that up front, is there a default)
4. Will you support find methods, sort methods, etc...
5. Can the programmer copying one collection into another larger collection? A smaller one?
6. Are you going to support FIFO, LIFO, bidirectional iteration, etc...

Creating a good generic collection will be difficult, so I recommend that you look at everything that you would want a collection to support and go from there.

So, yes your initial thoughts are still incomplete. At a minimum it needs a method to access the data and to know how much data is there.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement the `IList<T>` interface, it contains all the required signatures to build  own generic list class. [MSDN documentation for IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)